# How to Prove that a set is uncountably infinite if through bijection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I know that and know how to find a bijection between a set of infinite binary strings and its power set. I came to a first conclusion that there exists a bijection between set S={0,1}* and P(N).

But how do I use this to prove that S is uncountable? (uncountable infinity)

Add-on exercise for bijection practices, not homework.

Comment: A side note: $\{0,1\}^*$ usually denotes the set of finite strings of arbitrary length (see [Kleene star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star)), i.e. $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \{0,1\}^i$, which is countable. The standard notation for infinite sequences is $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ or $\{0,1\}^\omega$ (see [$\omega$-language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_language)).

Answer (score 1):

Because $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ is uncountable:

Indeed, let be $f$ a bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$. And let $A=\{n\in\Bbb N:n\notin f(n)\}$. Since $f$ is a bijection, there exists $m=f^{-1}(A)$. If $m\in A$, then (by definition of $A$) $m\notin f(m)=A$, so $m\notin A$. But then, again by definition of $A$, $m\in f(m)=A$, a contradiction. So that bijection deos not exisst.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a bijection in order to prove that -- the usual diagonal argument can be formulated about equally naturally in each case

**Theorem 1 (Cantor).** *No function $\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ is surjective*.

**Proof.** Let $f:\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$; we must prove that it is not surjective. Define $(s_n) \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ such that $s_n = 1-f(n)_n$, where $f(n)_n$ is the $n$th element of the sequence $f(n)$. Then $s$ is an element of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ that is not in the range of $f$, because for every $k\in\mathbb N$, $(s_n)$ has been constructed to differ from $f(k)$ at position $k$. Since there is an element of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ that is not in the range of $f$, $f$ is not surjective.

**Theorem 2 (Cantor).** *No function $\mathbb N\to\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is surjective*.

**Proof.** Let $f:\mathbb N\to\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$; we must prove that it is not surjective. Define $A \in \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ such as $A=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid n\notin f(n)\}$. Then $A$ is an element of $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ that is not in the range of $f$, because for every $k\in\mathbb N$, $A$ has been constructed such that $A$ and $f(k)$ differ in whether $k$ is a member of them. Since there is an element of $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ that is not in the range of $f$, $f$ is not surjective.

---

Once you have one of these theorems, you can of course use it to prove that the other set is uncountable too:

**Theorem 1, alternative proof:** Let $f:\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$; we must prove that it is not surjective. We know that there exists a bijection $g:\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}\to\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$. Then the composition $g\circ f$ is $\mathbb N\to\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$. By Theorem 2, $g\circ f$ is not surjective, so there is an $A\in P(\mathbb N)$ that is not in the range of $g\circ f$. But that means that $g^{-1}(A)$ (which exists because $g$ is surjective) is not in the range of $f$, so $f$ is not surjective either.

This is not much simpler than the direct proof, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can show for *arbitrary* sets $X$ that $|\mathcal{P}(X)| > |X|$, i.e. that no surjective map $f \,:\, X \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ exists.

Assume such a map $f$ *does* exist and define $$
  F = \{ x \in X \,:\, x \notin f(x) \} \in \mathcal{P}(X) \text{.}
$$
If $f$ is surjective, then there must be an $x \in X$ with $f(x) = F$. However, by the definition of $F$, if $x \in F$ then $x \notin f(x)$ and thus $F \neq f(x)$. But again by the definition of $F$, if $x \notin F$, then $x \in f(x)$, and again $F \neq f(x)$. So in fact, $f(x) = F$ for *no* $x \in X$, which contradics the surjectivity of $f$.

Thus we know that

1. A bijection, say $g$, from $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ exists
2. No surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ exists.

It follows that no surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ can exist, because if there *was* such a map, say $f$, then $g \circ f$ would be a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.